# Add unique ID to dynamic html that is generated on click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working on a php form seen on [here](http://www.firstusadata.com/cash_flow_test/) 
The buttons to add a new product and add a new vendor work correctly, however the appended divs created all currently share the same Div ID. So when you remove appended divs, they are all removed. 

Is there any way to add a unique ID to these appended divs so I can remove them individually?

You can view my full code in the snippet below or on my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8equu83d/)

```js
  function dynamic_html1(){
   var content = '<div class="dynamic_content_1">'
   +'<div class="row">'
      +'<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">'
       +'<div class="form-group w100">'
        +'<input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product" required >'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
       +'<div class="form-group  w100">'
        +'<input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price" required >'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
       +'<select class="form-control w100" id="" name="product_type[]" required >'
        +'<option value="">Select</option>'
        +'<option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>'
        +'<option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>'
       +'</select>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
       +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
        +'<button type="button" class="btn addproduct btn-default pull-left">'
         +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
        +'</button>'
        
        +'<button type="button" class="btn removeproduct btn-default pull-left">'
         +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
        +'</button>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>';
   return content;
  }
  
  

  
  
  
  function dynamic_html2(){
   var content =  '<div class="dynamic_content_2">'                    
  +'<div class="row">'
   +'<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 SecPageMain">'
               +'<h3>Vendor Information</h3>'
    +'<form method="post" action="http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow/companies/insert_company_information">'
     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Name of Company:</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" name="company_name" required="" >'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'

     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Company Phone Number:</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="" name="company_phone" required="" >'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'

     +'<div class="row margin_top_25">'
      +'<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
       +'<p>Did this company build your website?</p>'
      +'</div>'
          
      +'<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">'
       +'<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" >'
        +'<input type="radio"  value="1" name="built_website">'
        +'<label for="inlineRadio1"> Yes </label>'
       +'</div>'
       +'<div class="radio radio-inline">'
        +'<input type="radio"  value="0" name="built_website" checked>'
        +'<label for="inlineRadio2"> No </label>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     
     +'<div class="hide" id="BuildWebsite" >'
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Website URL:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="website_url" name="website_url">'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Type of Website:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" id="type_of_website" name="type_of_website">'
         +'<option value="Amazon Store">Amazon Store</option>'
         +'<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>'
         +'<option value="Drop Ship">Drop Ship</option>'
         +'<option value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</option>'
         +'<option value="Small Business">Small Business</option>'
         +'<option value="Landing Page">Landing Page</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10 category_area" style="display:none">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Category:</p>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" id="website_category" name="website_category">'
         +'<option value="">Select category</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      
      +'<div class="row margin_top_10">'
       +'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">'
        +'<p>Average Profit Margin Per 100 Users:</p>'
       +'</div>'
           
       +'<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">'
       +' <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100 price" id="average_profit" name="average_profit">'
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
     
     +'<div id="dynamic_content_2">'
      +'<div class="row margin_top_25 form-inline product_row">'
       +'<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">'
        +'<div class="form-group w100">'
         +'<input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product"  required>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-2">'
        +'<div class="form-group  w100">'
         +'<input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price"  required>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<select class="form-control w100" name="product_type[]" required>'
         +'<option value="">Select</option>'
         +'<option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>'
         +'<option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>'
        +'</select>'
       +'</div>'
       
       +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
         +'<button type="button" class="btn addproduct btn-default pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
         
         +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeproduct pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
        +'</div>' 
       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
                    
                    
           +'<h4>Add Vendor</h4>'         
            +'<div class="col-sm-3">'
        +'<div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">'
         +'<button type="button" class="btn addvendor btn-default pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
         
         +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removevendor pull-left">'
          +'<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'
         +'</button>'
        +'</div>'
       +'</div>'                 
    +'</form>'
   +'</div>'
  +'</div>'
       +' </div>';
   return content;
  }

 
  //alert(dynamic_html());
  
  $(document).on("click",".addproduct",function(){
   $(".dynamic_content_2").append(dynamic_html1());
  });
  
  $(document).on("click",".removeproduct",function(){
   var check = 0;
   $(".dynamic_content_2").each(function(){
    check++;
   });
   if(check>0){
    $(this).parents(".dynamic_content_2").remove();
   }
  });
  

  $(document).on("click",".addvendor",function(){
   $(".dynamic_content_1").append(dynamic_html2());
  });
  
  $(document).on("click",".removevendor",function(){
   var check = 0;
   $(".dynamic_content_1").each(function(){
    check++;
   });
   if(check>0){
    $(this).parents(".dynamic_content_1").remove();
   }
  });




  $(document).on("click","input[name='built_website']",function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   if(value==="1"){
    $("#BuildWebsite").removeClass("hide");
   }else{
    $("#BuildWebsite").addClass("hide");
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dynamic_content_1">                     
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 SecPageMain">
               <h3>Vendor Information</h3>
    <form method="post" action="http://firstusadata.com/cash_flow/companies/insert_company_information">
     <div class="row margin_top_25">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
       <p>Name of Company:</p>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" name="company_name" required='' >
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row margin_top_25">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
       <p>Company Phone Number:</p>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="" name="company_phone" required='' >
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="row margin_top_25">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
       <p>Did this company build your website?</p>
      </div>
          
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
       <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" >
        <input type="radio"  value="1" name="built_website">
        <label for="inlineRadio1"> Yes </label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio radio-inline">
        <input type="radio"  value="0" name="built_website" checked>
        <label for="inlineRadio2"> No </label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="hide" id="BuildWebsite" >
      <div class="row margin_top_10">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Website URL:</p>
       </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100" id="website_url" name="website_url">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row margin_top_10">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Type of Website:</p>
       </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control w100" id="type_of_website" name="type_of_website">
         <option value="Amazon Store">Amazon Store</option>
         <option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>
         <option value="Drop Ship">Drop Ship</option>
         <option value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</option>
         <option value="Small Business">Small Business</option>
         <option value="Landing Page">Landing Page</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row margin_top_10 category_area" style="display:none">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Category:</p>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control w100" id="website_category" name="website_category">
         <option value="">Select category</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row margin_top_10">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
        <p>Average Profit Margin Per 100 Users:</p>
       </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left w100 price" id="average_profit" name="average_profit">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="dynamic_content_2">
      <div class="row margin_top_25 form-inline product_row">
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group w100">
         <input type="" class="form-control  w100" id="" name="product_name[]" placeholder="Product"  required>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group  w100">
         <input type="" class="form-control w100 price" id="" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Price"  required>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control w100" name="product_type[]" required>
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="Web Development">Web Development</option>
         <option value="Business Development">Business Development</option>
        </select>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">
         <button type="button" class="btn addproduct btn-default pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
         
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeproduct pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
         </button>
        </div> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
                    
                    
           <h4>Add Vendor</h4>          
             <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-inline margin_left_25">
         <button type="button" class="btn addvendor btn-default pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
         
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removevendor pull-left">
          <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
         </button>
        </div> 
       </div>          
                    
                    
                    
                    
     
     <div class="row margin_top_25 margin_bottom_25"> 
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                          <div class="btn-inline">
         
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Summary</button>
               </div> 
      </div> 
     </div>

    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Simplify your example, it's hard/not-interesting to read bunch of text

Comment: I hope my edits were able to clear up my question a bit. 
I found a similar example here http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TTHDQ/12/
But I am unable to implement this into my own code. 
Any suggestions to add unique div id's to my appended elements would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at your [cash flow test](http://www.firstusadata.com/cash_flow_test/),  `dynamic_content_1` class gets nested inside the original `dynamic_content_1` when you create a new vendor. Is that your desired output?

Comment: I need to be able to append a new product field to each of the vendors that I add. Would there be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I haven't read your code, but in a general sense if the items are to be removed in response to the user clicking something you shouldn't need element ids at all, just a common class. If there is a delete button or checkbox in each row then you would use DOM navigation methods (.closest(), etc.) to relate the clicked button to the item to be deleted. If you need to delete the last one in the list then you'd use appropriate selectors and/or the .last() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a counter to your javascript `var i = 1` (outside the function scope) and increment this when you add a new instance of `dynamic_content_2`.
Change the first line of `dynamic_html2()` to read `var content = '<div class="dynamic_content_2" id="addedForm' + i +'">'`. At the end of the function, simply increment the value of `i`. `i++`.

Now change `.removevendor` click function to:

```
$(document).on("click",".removevendor",function(){
    i--;
    $('#addedForm' + i).remove();
});
```

This should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**
[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk4k5zr7/)

**EDIT 2:**

As [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) points out you can use `closest()`. Which is actually the better, and simpler method. You would change your `.removevendor` click function to:

```
$(document).on("click",".removevendor",function(){
    $(this).closest('.dynamic_content_2').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Duncan and @nnnnnn, your combined solutions worked perfectly. I was able to add my own function to append and remove products as well. 

I believe there are still some div issues that I am running into, as the content is not being appended to the proper areas after clicking the buttons, but this, I am sure I can figure out on my own. Thank You!